# Is there a convention for figuring out the MSB and LSB on a counter IC?

Tags: digital-logic, counter

Taking a look at the [74LS169](http://eeshop.unl.edu/pdf/DM74LS169.pdf), for instance, this IC has output pins Qa - Qd. I notice a lot of data sheets like these do not always specify which pin is the MSB or LSB of the count. Other than hooking it up and testing on a breadboard (or tracing through diagrams/schematics), is there something else to look for in the data sheets? I would think that D would be MSB and A would be LSB, but how often is that the case?

[image]

Comment: The timing diagram on [the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls169b.pdf?ts=1618615288891) at page 5 tells you everything you need to know. So do the schematics, as well, a page or so earlier. Are you having difficultly interpreting them? But in general you will need to examine each datasheet as there really isn't a standard. At least, I've experienced cases that differ with what I'd previously imagined as typical. So I know for any given assumption there is at least one counter-case.

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm not directly telling you for this specific case isn't about being a pain. It's about letting you work through the process of achieving the answer on your own. This is a good case where the datasheet has multiple ways of answering your question -- not just one -- and where you have the opportunity to exercise your mind a little bit. I think you can find out, just fine. If you report back that you cannot, then I can just tell you. But I don't want to steal that opportunity from you, just yet.

Comment: When interpreting that datasheet or similar, it is conventional to call the LSB the bit that changes most frequently.

Comment: If there's any doubt, you can read the internal circuit, it's in the datasheet.

Comment: Truthfully, I don't have any problems reading the diagrams and am aware that they contain the information but was curious if anyone noted any sort of trend over the years on the data sheets that would make identifying the LSB and MSB faster. Then there's the importance of reading diagrams fluently, which I will work on. Thank you for the input.

Comment: There are trends on data sheets, but there is no standard, each manufacturer does there own thing. I have been reading data sheets since the 70's and I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discrete counters, for all cases that I know of (and I've been around and doing this stuff for a **long** time), QA and Q0 always indicate the lsb. Likewise, for shift registers, QA will be the output closest to the  input, in terms of how quickly data gets shifted.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could comment since I am not sure if this qualifies as an answer. Although maybe I could provide some insight to what jonk is really telling you. If you understand counters. You will know how their behaviour works. In other words: You can look at the Timing Diagrams and see which bits change during counting. The LSB will be the one that changes on every rising edge of the clock. (I hope I phrased this properly.) In the case of the 74LS169 you can look at the Timing Diagrams and notice that Q_a changes state after every cycle of the clock. Hence is the LSB